# How to extract more than 500 records with Ajax from a database

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-table, data-extraction

I am pulling 'POST' data using an Ajax script and I am populating a table with the json data. Currently I am running into the issue where I can only extract 500 records at once. How can I extract more? Or is there a way to create a function that will put the data into pages? Or can I pull more data with a load more and then remove data when I don't need it?

Code:

```
 function populateTable(){       //populates the project list with active projects

 var reqBody1 = { "filters":{ "and": [] }}
 var $orgName = $('#orgName');


 $.ajax({        
 type: 'POST',
 url: "https://myWebsite.com/path/to/data",
 contentType: 'application/json',
 data: JSON.stringify(reqBody1),
 success: function(res){

    for (i=0; i <records.total ; i++){

        $orgName.append('<tr><td>' + res.records[i].field_1364364 + '</td></tr>');
            }
        }
});
}
```

Error:
[image: Network output on google chrome]

Comment: Perhaps your data source paginates its results for large sets of data?  Depending on your situation, if a given search would return more than some limit of results, that limit and a property that represents the total number of results could be returned.  APIs that take this approach are usually accompanied by some logic that allows one to choose an offset, then submit a second request for the remaining results beginning at that offset.

Comment: Hmm, `more than 500 records` error when the result is only 130 records? That's a bug in the API and you will have to ask the author of this API to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The "More than 500 records cannot be extracted at once" warning you're seeing is being returned by the API you're interacting with. It's not inherent to AJAX.

You will need to consult the documentation for this API to see if there is a workaround. In particular, check for an "offset" or "skip" option, or, if the results you're retrieving are sorted, see if you can limit the search to results which sort below the last one you retrieved.

Comment: Hi, I have an offset value how can I leverage it to extract more data? I really want to know how to make pages our of the JSON data I am extracting. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Read the documentation for the API you're using.